When should I use @Positive instead of @Min(1) in Spring Boot?
For validating a pagination parameter int size in Spring Boot, I want to ensure the value is greater than 0. I noticed that both @Positive and @Min(1) can be used for this.
Which one is better to use, and is there any practical difference between them? Which option is considered best practice in Spring Boot?

For pagination parameters, @Min(1) is the better choice because:

It's more explicit about requiring values >= 1
Pagination deals with whole numbers, and @Min(1) prevents decimal values (unlike @Positive which allows them)

Example:
@GetMapping("/users")
public Page<User> getUsers(
    @Min(1) @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") int page,
    @Min(1) @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") int size
) {
    return userService.findAll(PageRequest.of(page - 1, size));
}

Use @Positive only when you need to allow decimal values > 0, like for measurements or calculations.
